# D3D9's GetDirect3D return different d3d object from the original one on dual GPU laptop

Tags: c++, gpu, directx, direct3d

See the following code, I run it on a dual GPU laptop, force the test program  using nvidia card in the the nvidia control pannel. Pointer returned by `GetDirect3D` methord is different from the original `pD3D` pointer, so when I retrieve some information about the adapter using `GetAdapterIdentifier` or so, I got the wrong information, e.g. `Identifier.Description` returns Intel strings, absolutely it's not true.

No problems if I force the program using Intel card or on other platforms with only one GPU. Want to know why?

```
HRESULT hr;

IDirect3D9* pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(SDK_VERSION);
hr = pD3D->CreateDevice(xxxx, &pd3dDevice);

IDirect3D9* pParentD3D = NULL;
hr = pd3dDevice->GetDirect3D(&pParentD3D);
```

Comment: Pointers can be proxied by COM, or even be part of a multiple-inheritance C++ class. You can make no assumptions.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis No, not only the pointer value, as I said, information such as adapterinfo retrieved from the returned object is not correct.